# Cordova peer-to-peer app using webRTC

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webrtc, p2p

I have to build a cross-platform peer-to-peer application (at least support iOS & Android). For that I am using Cordova. Currently I can do service discovery using the ZeroConf plugin. Now **I would want to make a peer-to-peer connection on discovery.**

An equivalent app has already been made using Titanium. After discovery, it uses sockets to connect to the discovered machine.

```
/*
    Service Discovery resulting in an IP address and port number
    ...
*/

socket = Titanium.Network.createTCPSocket({
    hostName: discoveredHostName,
    port: discoveredPort,
    mode: Titanium.Network.READ_WRITE_MODE
});
...
socket.connect();
```

However, **I need to translate the app to Cordova, hence i will need an alternative to those sockets used in the Titanium version.** Using an intermediary server is not an option (only for signaling it may be used, not for message exchange).

My mentor advised to use webRTC as it is a simple standard Javascript API, mentioning it works on iOS referring to the [official website which metions iOS support](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/). I implemented it, testing it in the browser and it works like a charm.

However, **when testing it on iOS webRTC does not work** :

```
var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection;
```

This works in the browser, but on iOS this results in `RTCPeerConnection` being `undefined`. **I presume i am missing something, as the official website mentions iOS support?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebRTC is **not supported** by Safari, both **MacOS** and **iOS**:

see http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc

The article cited (https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) refers to a native development on iOS using, I think, a library or an SDK which implements WebRTC API.

Using Cordova Framework you can't rely natively on a WebView WebRTC enabled, but you have to adopt a specific plugin or subtituite the Cordova WebView with [Crosswalk](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjthvn1zKTLAhXEXCwKHVVTAJYQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcrosswalk-project.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNEQG42yNGVjci50tejZwbThceYDiQ&sig2=4_c9bPv6VaVzv8sgKfiFCA) (for example).

On iOS a plugin implementing w3c WebRTC APIs is [iosrtc](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc), but it has some [issues](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/issues) pending and some limitation on [video](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc#usage) element implementation.

Comment: Ok, that's what i was thinking, thank you! Definitely this won't make it easier.. I saw a WebRTC plugin for Cordova, will give it a try. Does some webRTC plugin exist which is compatible with iOS as well as Android? On a side note : This means that it's not possible to use webRTC with interoperability between iOS, Android and a pc ? (This is beyond the scope of my task but pure curiosity). This is the plugin i'm talking about : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-webrtc

Comment: Personally I developed a Cordova/Ionic app using Crosswalk for Android version, and using cordova-plugin-iosrtc for iOS version. There are several cordova WebRTC plugins but each of them has a limitation. Interoperability among different devices on different platform is possible thanks to WebRTC: my applications (web, Android and iOS) interact among them successfully.

Comment: The problem is i will have to integrate my work into a big project, the idea being that afterwards the whole project is not bound to Cordova (or Ionic) but can be ran using the Titanium version or the Cordova version of the networking part. I am afraid that i will make the whole project bound to Cordova, hence as i only need to be able to send text, a simple plugin (ideally compatible with iOS and Android) providing a data channel would be nice but does not seem to exist.

Comment: Maybe the cordova plugin you mentioned could fit for you, in fact they declare support for RTCDataChannel and it supports bot iOS and Android.

Comment: They mention "Android 4.0+ coming soon" hence i'm afraid it is not yet supported, but I will give it a try. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice... WebRTC, at present, is not a mature technology. Keep in mind that other standards are in development (http://ortc.org/)

Comment: I tried iosrtc and it works very well, thanks for sharing :)